# UDF value error for complex itterative function

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions

I want to create an UDF for my excel worksheet. However when I select my input for my UDF I get a value error. Can someone help me?

Code and images below:

code:

```
Public Function pipediameter(Pth As Double) As Double


Dim D As Double


p = 150
Tv = 30
T = 55
k = 0.000045
vi = 4
a = (1.729 * (10 ^ (-6))) / ((1 + (T / 25)) ^ 1.165)
rho = 988
Cp = 4180

di = 1
i = 1

    While i <= 10
    v = 4 * Pth / (3.14 * di ^ 2 * Cp * rho * Tv)
    Re = v * di / vi
    B1 = (0.774 * Log(Re) - 1.41) / (1 + 1.32 * Sqr(k / di))
    B2 = ((k * Re) / (3.7 * di)) + (2.51 * B1)
    Y = (B1 - ((B1 + (2 * (Log(B2 / Re) / Log(10)))) / (1 + (2.18 / B2)))) ^ (-2)
    
    D = (((8 * Y) / (p * rho)) * ((Pth) / (3.14 * Cp * Tv)) ^ 2) ^ 0.2
    
    
    di = D
    i = i + 1
    Wend


pipediameter = D
End Function
```

[image: 1]

Comment: `Pi` is not what you think it is.  As you are using it it is an empty variant not `3.14...`  If you use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables this would have told you the problem.

Comment: you want `WorksheetFunction.Pi`

Comment: It does not solve my problem. I still get the error. I changed all the "Pi" to 3.14

Comment: did you do both instances of `Pi`?  It works for me once I fixed that.

Comment: I edited the code so you can see what the new version looks like

Comment: Your first code did not have `()` for the `V` line.  By adding you create negative numbers and you can't take the log of negative numbers. so it errors on the Y line.  At this point it is no longer a vba issue but a math issue.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not know what you mean with () and V line and how I create negative numbers...

Comment: Your first code block had `v = 4 * Pth / 3.14 * di ^ 2 * Cp * rho * Tv` and the edit you put in `()`: `v = 4 * Pth / (3.14 * di ^ 2 * Cp * rho * Tv)`  This is causing B1 and B2 to be negative.  You cannot take the Log of a negative number.  That is your error.

Comment: Thanks ! It works